# how can define double type to onChange Event param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

im using React onChange in input tag.
and i faced problem about type definication.

look this code

```
  onChange?: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | SeperationChangeEvent) => void;
```

and im using like this

```
const Foo = () => {
 const handleChange = (e : ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {}
 return <Input onChange={handleChange}/>
}
```

below error pic
how can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Or `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: i did but same error

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something?

Comment: Where is that `<Input/>` component comes from? Can you share that too, why does it expecting a union type. What is wrong here seems like your input component.

Comment: This looks like a misunderstanding of how function types work in TypeScript. Functions are **contravariant**, which you can read all about [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/#3-contravariance).

Answer (score 0):

React exports its own ChangeEvent that is different than the built in one.

```
const Foo = () => {
  const handleChange = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {}

  return <Input onChange={handleChange}/>
}
```

Comment: of course i did like your answer